# How to resolve the "Declaration not found" issue in KDevelop?

Tags: c, linux, kdevelop

I am using `KDevelop` on `Xubuntu 15.04`. Everything seems fine except that from time to time, it cannot resolve the function declarations. Such as below one:

[image]

I tried to explicitly add the `/usr/include/time.h` to the Include paths as below:

[image]

But the whole KDevelop will **hang**.

Anyone see such issue?

I prefer KDevelop to Eclipse because the performance is better on a VM.

### ADD 1

I found a similar bug report here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=237420

Though this issue is shown in the Editor window, the project compiles smoothly.

Comment: You shouldn't add file, you need add direrectory instead, also don't forget press Apply button.

Comment: @Gluttton But it says `A new include path/file to use for parsing files under given directory`. Anyway, I will try to use the path.

Comment: Such approach works good for me with Qt (so I share my experience).

Comment: @Gluttton thanks. I just tried to add the `/usr/include/` This time it doesn't hang. But still the `time` cannot be recognized.